# Trouble rotating matrix with python

Tags: python, matrix

I've created a function that successfully rotates the outside layer of a matrix.  I've tried adding a loop so that it does the same thing for the interior layers of the matrix, but I haven't had any luck.

```
def rotateMatrix(mat,size):
    temp = []
    for i in range(size):
        temp.append(mat[0][i])
    for i in range(size-1):
        mat[0][i] = mat[size-(1+i)][0]
        mat[size-(1+i)][0] = mat[size-1][size-(1+i)]
        mat[size-1][size-(1+i)] = mat[0+i][size-1]
        mat[0+i][size-1] = temp[i]
    return mat
```

Is there a way I could change this slightly to allow for rotation of the interior layers?

I am trying to do this without using any libraries or built in functions.

Comment: I don't want to bother you too much, but range() is a built in function, which you did not want to use ;).

Comment: Fair enough, but I meant no built in functions to deal with the matrix.

Comment: I think the title of this questoin is a bit misleading.  When I think 'rotate a matrix', I think 'multiply a matrix by a rotation transformation'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rotate the matrix by 90 degrees.
Notice the rotation is not done in-place, another matrix is allocated for the result.

```
def rotate_matrix(matrix):
    size = len(matrix) 
    # init rotated matrix with None elements
    rotated_matrix = [[None]*size for _ in range(size)]
    for i in xrange(size):
        for j in xrange(size):
            rotated_matrix[j][size-1-i] = matrix[i][j]
    return rotated_matrix


matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]
rotated_matrix = rotate_matrix(matrix)
print rotated_matrix
>> [[7, 4, 1],
>>  [8, 5, 2],
>>  [9, 6, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [numpy.transpose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
>>> np.transpose(x)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it without any libraries.  I probably should have specified that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as shown in the following:

```
>>> a = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> list(zip(*a))
[(0, 2), (1, 3)]
>>> list(map(list, list(zip(*a))))
[[0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: I'm aware of zip as well, I just wanted to implement this function from scratch so I can understand how to work with a matrix a little better.